# SyntaxError: missing ; (semicolon) before statement - Razor

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, syntax

The block of code below triggers a `SyntaxError` on a missing `;`.  Here is a screenshot of Firebug's output:

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#SelectedMCO").change(function () {

    var scheme = @Request.Url.Scheme.ToString();
    var authority = @Request.Url.Authority.ToString();
    var applicationPath = @Request.ApplicationPath.ToString();

    var url = scheme + "://" + authority + applicationPath +"mytest/" + $("#Selectedoption").val();

    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
      $("#Selectedsub").empty();
      $.each(data, function(idx, obj) {
        $('#SelectedSub').append('<option value="' + obj.EntityNumber +'">' + obj.Name + '</option>');
      });
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: can you provide the actual error message? js error messages can be quite cryptic if you don't know what to look for.

Comment: What is `@Request`?

Comment: What is `@Request` supposed to mean? It's not JavaScript; is there some other library/framework involved?

Comment: @Request is a HttpRequestBase object.

Comment: HttpRequestBase WebPageRenderingBase.Request

Answer (score 2):

You just need to enclose your Razor variables in quotes:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#SelectedMCO").change(function () {

            var scheme = '@Request.Url.Scheme.ToString()';
            var authority = '@Request.Url.Authority.ToString()';
            var applicationPath = '@Request.ApplicationPath.ToString()';

            var url = scheme + "://" + authority + applicationPath 
                      +"mytest/" + $("#Selectedoption").val();

            $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
                $("#Selectedsub").empty();
                $.each(data, function(idx, obj) {
                    $('#SelectedSub').append('<option value="' + 
                      obj.EntityNumber +'">' + obj.Name + '</option>');
                });
            });
        });
    });
  </script>
```

This will ensure that your variables will be interpreted as strings by the JavaScript interpreter.

Comment: It worked :) Thank you very much Matt Spinks. I spent several hours on this. Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction.